# Uncaught ReferenceError: connectWin is not defined ! SenchaTouch

Tags: sencha-touch, undefined-reference, referenceerror

Following Problem:
I got the viewClass "connectWin" and the controllerClass "connectWinController".
The whole program starts with the view "connectWin", so if the button "Start" is tapped, 
the connectWinController should hide the "connectWin", do some stuff and open another view
"orderView". But if I tap the "Start" Button, I get the Error on my console.

**Heres the Code:**

**app.js :**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});


Ext.application({

    name: 'SenchaDiagApp',



    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.Img'
    ],

    refs: {

        connectWin: 'connectWin'
    },  

    launch: function() {
        console.log("App launch!!"); 



         connectWin= {

            layout: 'fit',
                items: [{

                    xtype : 'connectWin'
                }],
            }; 
        Ext.Viewport.add(connectWin);   

    }

});
```

**connectWin**:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.connectWin' , {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',  
    alias : 'widget.connectWin', 


    config:{
        ui : 'light',
        items: [
            {

                 xtype:         'panel',       
                 scrollable:    false,
                 centered:      true,
                 modal:         true,
                 width:         '100%',
                 height:        '50%', 

                    items: [ 

                        {

            xtype:      'titlebar',
                        docked:     'top',
                        height:     '110px',
                id:         'connectTitleID',
                        title:      'Login'
                    },

                {
                        xtype:       'spacer'
                    },




                {
                        xtype:      'titlebar', // 2 Titlebar unten 
                        docked:     'bottom',
                        height:     '110px',

                              items:[                       

                               {   
                                     xtype:     'button',
                                     align:     'left',
                     height:    '100px',
                     width: '200px',
                                     action:     'bestellen',
                     text:      'Start',
                                   }],


            }],              
        },
    });
```

**connectWinController:**

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.connectWinController', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config:{


                refs: {

                connectWin: 'connectWin'

                                 }
            },

    init: function() {

    this.control(
          'connectWin button[action=bestellen]':{

           tap: this.verbindungBestellung 

        },
    },


          verbindungBestellung : function(){
                            console.log("Start");
                connectWin.hide()  **//Now it says: connectWin is not defined?**


                             var orderView = Ext.create('AM.view.orderView');
                             Ext.Viewport.add(orderView);
                    }


        });
                                    '
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare every view , controller , model , store whatever you are using in ur application in `app.js`:

```
Ext.application({       
    name: 'AppName',
    requires: [],
    models:['Model-1','Model-2'],
    controllers : ['Main'],
    views : ['View-1','View-2'],
    stores : [ 'Store-1' , 'Store-2'],

    launch : function() {
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xclass: 'AppName.view.View-1',
            autoDestroy: false,
            showAnimation:false
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller, to get reference of your view,

ref:{

connectWin: { autoCreate:true,selector:'#connectWin',xtype:'connectWin' },

}

Use xtype:'connectWin' instead of alias...